# install opencv 3.4.1 and Qt 5.10 with CMAKE

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake, opencv3.0, qt5.10

I install **Qt 5.10** latest version and **opencv3.4.1** and I couldn't install the library in this version of Qt with **Cmake** can anybody help me to do it on my windows 10 64-bit please? 
I tried with this video also 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOSu-2Oju-A
and in cmd step I have this (picture in this link)
[image: that what I have when I write mingw32-make]

in this link also (( https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows ))  I do all  steps carefully but I didn't found the folder bin in opencv-build after do the steps and My OS is windows 10 64-bit thanks for help.

Comment: `I couldn't install the library` - What **exactly** is a problem? Did you encounter CMake error/compiler error or so? [edit] your question post with a description of your problem.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, what is the OS you are working with?

Comment: Yes i know this folder I have to create but sorry I mean the folder still empty after cmd step because it didn't complete to 100% and stop at 29% declear in pic in the post why it is not complete ??

Comment: It means your version of mingw does not default to c++11 support.

Comment: How I know what is the right version please ? According to my OS ? And if it 64 or 32-bit ?? Or the version of cmake ?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: I'm basing my answer more on [[SO]: openCV mingw-32 error in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629751/opencv-mingw-32-error-in-cmd) (the tools versions mentioned in the posted *.pdf*)

### 1. Preliminary considerations

At the beginning, I tried to build it using what I already had on my machine (*Win 10*):

- *CMake 3.6.4* (bundled by *Android Studio* - that I didn't updated for months *BTW*), ***cmdline*** - as there's no *GUI*
- *MinGW7.2.0* (that I built on my machine for a different task)

  - *g++ 7.2.0*
- *OpenCV 3.4.2* (downloaded [[GitHub]: opencv/opencv - opencv-3.4.2.zip](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.2.zip), specifically for this task)

The build process **passed this stage** (well, it failed somewhere below this point, I didn't check why exactly).
Anyway, I thought that the build env that I used, and the suggested one were too far away, so I:

- Downloaded *CMake 3.6.3* *Win x64* bundle (that contains *cmake-gui* - as *cmdline* can be a pain, especially for those that are not used to it)
- Used *MinGW 5.3.0* (part of my *Qt* installation)

  - *g++ 5.3.0*

The problem at its core (as specified in comments, or *Google*ing the error) is that the *g++* compiler doesn't use the *C++11* standard (and *protobuf* source code requires it). 
So, I did a little test: pasted the faulty code in a file (and added a dummy *main*), and tried it with the 2 *MinGW* installations.

*code00.cpp*:

```cpp
template <typename char_type>
bool null_or_empty(const char_type *s) {
    return (s == nullptr) || (*s == 0);
}


int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049459395]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> build
> build.bat
> cmake-gui.exe - Shortcut.lnk
> code.cpp
> src
>
> [prompt]> set _PATH=%PATH%
>
> [prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%;c:\Install\x64\MinGW32\MinGW32\7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\x64\MinGW32\MinGW32\7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin\g++" code.cpp
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\x64\MinGW32\MinGW32\7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin\g++" --version
> g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.2.0
> Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> a.exe
> build
> build.bat
> cmake-gui.exe - Shortcut.lnk
> code.cpp
> src
>
> [prompt]> del /q a.exe
>
> [prompt]> set PATH=%_PATH%;c:\Install\Qt\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\Qt\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\g++" code.cpp
> code.cpp: In function 'bool null_or_empty(const char_type*)':
> code.cpp:3:17: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
>      return (s == nullptr) || (*s == 0);
>                   ^
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\Qt\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\g++" --version
> g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.3.0
> Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\Qt\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\g++" code.cpp -std=c++0x
>
> [prompt]>
> ```

As seen, the older *g++* needs `-std=c++0x` **explicitly**.

Following the build steps, I got the same error as in the image below (I launched *mingw32-make* directly in *protobuf*'s dir, to skip all the other stuff built before it):

[image: protobuf build failed]

### 2. Solutions

Both are done at *cmake-gui* level. After setting the paths:

- Hit "*Configure*"
- **Do the required variable changes**
- Hit "*Generate*"
- Launch *mingw32-make* from console, in the build dir

**Notes**:

- Since I'm very far away from being a *CMake* expert, before doing this, I empty the build dir to make sure that there's nothing left from previous build (of course the drawback is that everything is done again, which usually takes a long time)
- Since I didn't enable parallel build, I didn't wait for the full build to finish (as it takes forever), but just checked that it passes this point

#### 2.1 Force *C++11* standard

Click "*Add Entry*" and set [[CMake 3.1]: CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html?highlight=cxx_standard):

[image: C++11]

And below, notice that the build passed point where it was failing before:

[image: protobuf build succeeded]

#### 2.2 Skip *Protobuf* build

**Notes**:

- In the posted movie, there's no *Protobuf* build attempted (probably it's not in the bundle?) that's why this error didn't pop up
- I don't know what functionality will not be available in the final build, as I don't know what *Protobuf* is used at
- I consider this more like a workaround

Search for *Protobuf* related variables, and **uncheck** any that are in the *BUILD* or *WITH* groups (the **blue** lines):

[image: Skip protobuf]

And again the effect is below - the *Protobuf* build no longer takes place (it comes just after *libIlmImf*):

[image: protobuf build skipped]